# FFTW.jl for 2D array: Diffusion only happening in 1D

Tags: julia, fft, fftw, differentialequations.jl

From what I have read, using FFTW.jl / AbstractFFTs.jl's fft(A) when A is a 2D array should perform fft in 2D, not column-wise. Any idea why I am seeing only column-wise diffusion when (I think) I'm adding scaled second spatial derivative to u(t,x), as if using explicit solver for time?

Thank you! I am quite new to this.

[code and heatmap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV1oY.png)

```
using Random
using FFTW
using Plots

gr()

N = (100,100)

# initialize with gaussian noise
u = randn(Float16, (N[1], N[2])).*0.4.+0.4
# include square of high concentration to observe diffusion clearly
u[40:50,40:50] .= 3

N = size(x)
L = 100
k1 = fftfreq(51)
k2 = fftfreq(51)
lap_mat = -(k1.^2 + k2.^2)

function lap_fft(x)
    lapF = rfft(x)
    lap = irfft(lap_mat.*lapF, 100)
    return lap
end

# ode stepper or Implicit-Explicit solver
for i in 1:100000
    u+=lap_fft(u)*0.0001
end
# plot state
heatmap(u)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you are performing a real FFT, doesn't mean that you can real inverse fft the result. rfft goes from R -> C. What you can however do is the following:

```
function lap_fft(x)
    lapF = complex(zeros(100,100));        # only upper half filled
    lapF[1:51,1:100] = rfft(x) .* lap_mat; # R -> C
    return abs.(ifft(lapF));               # C -> R
end
```

Real FFT to complex frequency domain (only upper half filled because of data redundancy), multiply your filter in frequency domain, inverse FFT into complex image domain and obtain the magnitude `abs.()`, real part `real.()` etc.
But honestly, why the hassle with the real fft?

```
using Random
using FFTW
using Plots

gr()

N = (100,100)

# initialize with gaussian noise
u = randn(Float16, (N[1], N[2])).*0.4.+0.4;
# include square of high concentration to observe diffusion clearly
u[40:50,40:50] .= 3;

N = size(u);
L = 100;
k1 = fftfreq(100);
k2 = fftfreq(100);
tmp = -(k1.^2 + k2.^2);
lap_mat = sqrt.(tmp.*reshape(tmp,1,100));


function lap_fft(x)
    return abs.(ifftshift(ifft(fftshift(ifftshift(fft(fftshift(x))).*lap_mat))));
end

# ode stepper or Implicit-Explicit solver
for i in 1:100000
    u+=lap_fft(u)*0.001;
end
# plot state
heatmap(u)
```

[image]